# how can i get useState value inside useCallback (react hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, usecallback

i can't get the useState value that inside of useCallback. when i run the code below,

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const DBLab = () => {
    const [hashHistory, setHashHistory] = useState("initial_value");
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    const didAuthMountRef = useRef(false);

    const set = useCallback(() => {
        const decodeHash = decodeURI(window.location.hash);
        console.log();
        console.log("decodeHash: " + decodeHash);
        console.log("hashHistory: "+ hashHistory);
        setHashHistory(decodeHash);
    },[hashHistory]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const startFunc = async() => {
            set();
            window.addEventListener('hashchange', set);
            didAuthMountRef.current = true;
        }
        if(!didAuthMountRef.current) {
            startFunc();
        }
    }, [set]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>dblab</h1>
            <h1>{hashHistory}</h1>
            <input type='text' value={inputValue} onChange={(e)=>setInputValue(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DBLab;
```

in web console, i get

```
decodeHash: #/dblab#first

hashHistory: initial_value
```

which is right. but when i change url to http://localhost:3000/#/dblab#next, i get

```
decodeHash: #/dblab#next

hashHistory: initial_value
```

this is wrong. because hashHistory has not changed. but it is not useState problem. because hashHistory that i see with `<h1>{hashHistory}</h1>` in screen is `#/dblab#next` which is the right hash.

how can i get the right hashHistory inside of useCallback?.

ps. i must have to use `useCallback`.

Comment: You're not cleaning up that event listener correctly, for one. You might want to use a hook that does things correctly for you, such as https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useHash.md

Comment: @AKX wow. what a document! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const startFunc = () => {
        if(!didAuthMountRef.current) {
            set();
            didAuthMountRef.current = true;
        }
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', set);
    }
    startFunc();
    return ()=> {
        window.removeEventListener('hashchange', set);
    }
}, [set]);
```

Logic problem

Comment: So smart! but do you know why useEffect add evnetListener once?  Isn't 'useEffect' executed every time the 'set' function is executed?

Comment: @importJWE No, it's executed every time the `set` function's identity changes.

Comment: @importJWE set(exec)=>hasHistory(change)=>set(change)=>useEffect(release)=>useEffect(exec)

Comment: @AKX identity changes?

Comment: @importJWE See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects